# How to rewrite a URL using htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have read a few articles on rewriting using .htaccess and I still cannot fully get the outcome I was hoping for.

I have a url called: sitename.co.nf/Profile.php?u=Admin

Admin is my username.
I want to know how to rewrite the url as sitename.co.nf/$username

$username is a variable I have set up in my PHP code.

I tried using this rewrite without luck `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/?$ Profile.php?u=$1`

Here is some other userful code you may want to see...

```
if (isset($_GET['u'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET['u']);
    if (ctype_alnum($username)) {
    //check user exists
    $check = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($check)===1) {
    $get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check);
    $username = $get['username'];


    }
```

Comment: And what's the actual outcome? How does it differ from your expectations?

Comment: When I log into my account i am redirected to my Profile.php page. The url is still website.co.nf/Profile.php?u=Admin

It is not rewriting to website.co.nf/Admin

Comment: Yes, RewriteRules are only for *incoming* URLs.

Comment: I hope nobody named `Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--` signs up for an account...

Comment: Do i need to use mod_rewrite?